# Javascript - get value from FileReader asynchronous onload method

Tags: javascript, angular, filereader

I know that this question has been asked many times here but I have looked at these answers and couldn't make my code work. I'm using Angular 2.
I have input tags for file insertion. File gets to component but when I convert it to array buffer and try to set it to variable my variable remains undefined. I tried to implement callbacks but I think I have done it wrong.

Here is my code:

```
addPlayer() {
    var nationality = document.getElementById("nationality") as HTMLSelectElement;
    var position = document.getElementById("position") as HTMLSelectElement;
    var shirtnmbr = document.getElementById("shirtnmbr") as HTMLSelectElement;
    var profilePicture = document.getElementById("profilepic") as HTMLSelectElement;
    var inGamePicture = document.getElementById("detailspic") as HTMLSelectElement;
    var player = {
        Club_ID: this.clubId,
        Name: this.capitalization(this.addForm.get("name").value),
        Surname: this.capitalization(this.addForm.get("surname").value),
        Height: this.addForm.get("height").value,
        Weight: this.addForm.get("weight").value,
        BirthDate: this.addForm.get("birthdate").value.formatted,
        Nationality: this.nationalities[nationality.selectedIndex],
        Position: this.order[position.selectedIndex],
        Shirtnmbr: this.shirtNumbers[shirtnmbr.selectedIndex],
        ProfilePicture: this.conversion(profilePicture, function (res) {
            return res;
        }),
        InGamePicture: this.conversion(inGamePicture, function (res) {
            return res;
        })
    };
    console.log(player);  
}

capitalization(str) {
    return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function (txt) { return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase(); });
}

conversion(element, callback) {
    var file = element.files;
    var result;
    var fileReader = new FileReader();
    fileReader.onload = function () {
        result = fileReader.result;
        callback(result);
    };
    fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(file[0]);
}
```

When I log player every property has value except ProfilePicture and InGamePicture(they are undefined). After that I'm planning to send that player to database but currently I can't do that because http.post would run before ProfilePicture and InGamePicture properties get values.

Comment: You need to ensure both call backs have completed before you send your data to HTTP i assume? Also just a suggestion, you should use promises or because using Angular 2 then you should use RXJS instead of callbacks.

Comment: @LiverpoolOwen can you provide an example how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting `ProfilePicture` and `InGamePicture` to values equal to the return value of `conversion()`, which never returns anything so they will always be `undefined`. You give a callback which you call, but it does actual nothing (returns the parameter which is never handled).

You need to synchronously complete both `FileReader` operations before proceeding. If you can only get the results asynchronously then this sounds like a job for [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), the preferred way these days to handle control flow with multiple asynchronous operations.

Comment: No, it does not? It sets an onload that *calls* the callback, which only returns the parameter it is given, then immediately discards the result (the `callback(result)` expression is just ran and not stored, hence its return value will be discarded). All this is asynchronous. The `onload` setting does not block program flow and the function will return immediately (with an `undefined` return value).

Comment: that is exactly the problem that I'm facing with. I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Without delving too deep, as I said, refactoring the control flow as promises would probably accomplish what you want. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495796/javascript-promises-with-filereader for a similar problem.

Comment: I am looking at that example but I don't get how it works. To be precise, I don't know how to implement promises in my code.

Comment: @jlaitio can you tell me how can I store callback(result) to get return value from that function? I'm not familiar with promises.