# Why is setState not working when using FileReader to read file content?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render, setstate

I'm making a file input to select multiple images that can be pre-visualized.

To handle multiple images I put them in an array of the component's state, and map the pre-visualized images.

But when I select the images from the input and set the state with `this.setState({imgArray: newArray})`, `this.state.array.map(image=><img src={image}/>)` doesn't re-render the selected images.

**Code:**

```
export default class posts extends Component {
  state = {
    fotos: ["/iconos/img.svg"] // If there are not img selected, it renders one image icon
  }

  onUploadVarious = e => {
    let newArray = []
    Object.values(e.target.files).map(file => {
      let nuevo = new FileReader()
      nuevo.onload = event=> newArray.push(event.target.result)
      nuevo.readAsDataURL(file)}
    )
    this.setState({fotos: newArray}) // the state is set correctly
  }
}
```

**Render:**

```
<div className=" border rounded" style={{"height":"30%", "overflow":"auto"}}>
    {this.state.fotos.map(foto =>
      <img src={foto||"/iconos/img.svg"}
        id="arch-preview"/>)} // it doesn't re-render when fotos state is changed
</div>

// input
<div className="mt-auto">
    <input multiple="multiple" type="file" 
    onChange={this.onUploadVarious} 
    className="form-control-file" name="file" />
</div>
```

Comment: `readAsDataURL` is asynchronous, so you need to call the `setState` _after_ that data is read, which should be in the `onload` function I believe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) reads file content **asynchronously**.

Due to this asynchronous nature, state is being set i.e. `this.setState({fotos: newArray})` before **data urls** are set in `newArray` i.e. `newArray.push(event.target.result)`.

And that's the reason your selected files *aren't showing up*.

To fix it, you can use create `Promise` which gets resolved after `load` event of each file. And use `Promise.all` which would be resolved after each Promise has resolved and then use `setState`:

```
readAsDataURL = (file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const fr = new FileReader()
    fr.onerror = reject
    fr.onload = function () {
      resolve(fr.result)
    }
    fr.readAsDataURL(file)
  })
}

onUploadVarious = (e) => {
  Promise.all(Array.from(e.target.files).map(this.readAsDataURL))
    .then((urls) => {
      this.setState({ fotos: urls })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error)
    })
}
```

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) has some good examples of **Promises and their executing orders**. Also check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34495796/2873538) about using *FileReader* with *Promise*.