# React.js, attribute in object is undefined but exist in object with non-null value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to add picture files with Dropzone and show preview on browser.
So, I have to get `src` which can use at `<img />`. So I do this process:

```
  const handleAddImages = async (inputImages: any[]): Promise<void> => {
    const imagesWithSrc = inputImages.map((img) => {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result);
        reader.onerror = reject;
        reader.readAsDataURL(img);
      }).then(() => (img.src = reader.result));
      return img;
    });

    const nextImages = [...currentImages, ...imagesWithSrc];
    handleOnChange({
     //set state
      target: {
        name: "images",
        value: nextImages,
      },
    });
  };
```

And show the images in this component:

```
export const FileList = ({
  images
}: any) => {
  const imgs: any[] = images;

  return (
      <Wrapper>
        {imgs.map((img, index) => (
            <ImgBox key={index}>
              <img src={img.src} />
            </ImgBox>
        ))}
      </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

I have an images array `imgs` and contains image file objects.
When I do this:

```
console.log(imgs[0]);
```

it will output every attributes in image file object of index 0 including the image source `src` in base64 from filereader API.

but when I do this:

```
console.log(imgs[0].src);
```

it will output `undefined`,

even I do console.log in map like this:

```
imgs.map((img, index) => {
  console.log(img);
  console.log(img.src);
})
```

and get the same result, what is the problem?

```
console.log("imgs[0]", imgs[0]); 
console.log("imgs[0].src", imgs[0].src);
```

ouput:

[image]

By the way, I can get the size attribute by `imgs[0].size` at first,
and get the `imgs[0].src` after add another picture.

Comment: Can you post output of `console.log(imgs[0]);`?

Comment: Please may you share an example of what `imgs` is?

Comment: I posted output capture of imgs[0] and imgs[0].src.

Comment: imgs[0].File.src

Comment: @Ernesto Thanks for your help, but the File is exactly what the imgs[0] is, I just add the code of console.log I wrote.

Comment: If you `console.log(JSON.stringify(imgs);` you’ll see more clearly how how yow data is structured

Comment: @Ernesto I tried `console.log(JSON.stringify(imgs[0]));` , it did not contain the `src`, but the `src` exists in output by `console.log(imgs[0]);` run before JSON.stringify one. What would cause this? By the way I can get `imgs[0].src` if refreshes the page once.

Comment: Hi, can you post a larger portion of your code? How are you setting up this imgs array?

Answer (score 0):

As defined in the [W3C File API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI), the [File](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-file) interface (which extends [Blob](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#dfn-Blob)) does NOT have an `src` property. While your environment may display an `src` property, it appears to be inaccessable from your code, and may be added by your browser's runtime or another part of your code in a way that makes it inaccessable. Honestly, without more information, I cannot say for sure where the `src` property is coming from.

If you want to base64-ify your File object, try using the [FileReader](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#APIASynch) API:

```js
let blob = imgs[0];

let reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(blob);

reader.onload = function() {
  console.log(reader.result); //-> "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw..."
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I add the part of adding `src` property. maybe it help for finding the reason I can access the `src`.

Comment: Oh, you've got a whole other problem here. You're not awaiting the Promise inside the lambda passed to `inputImages.map`. The `src` property wont be updated until after all your code has been executed and the React render is complete.

Comment: but why I can see the `src` in the output by `console.log(imgs[0])` but undefined by `console.log(imgs[0].src)`??

Comment: Hmm, good point, I think the path to a solution would involve you restructuring your code to wait for the encoding to complete (which I'm almost certain is your problem) and also not modifying an object that is part of an API that you don't manage in your own code (that's just good practice, and will make your code easier to maintain and reason about. Consider returning an object like { file, src }, and make sure to use await to wait for the encoding to complete.

Comment: yeah, I thought that restructuring is a good idea, too. Anyway thanks for your help and suggestion, and I will try to solve it in another way to process file.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be problem with filereader API and I solved my problem with this answer.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34495914/16426251