# Javascript FileReader onerror event - how to find out what the error was?

Tags: javascript, filereader

the Javascript `FileReader` object supports an `onerror` handler that gets called when there has been an error, but the event passed in is a `ProgressEvent` and doesn't contain any details of the error.

How can I find out what actual error occurred?

Comment: Could you please add the snippet of your code for us to better understand the problem?

Comment: I think this link might help you: [File and FileReader](https://javascript.info/file)

Answer (score 5):

After RTFMing a little more closely in response to @Ariel's comment (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/error), I see that FileReader has an `error` property as well as an `error` event. When the error handler is called, the the `ProgressEvent` passed to it is next to useless and you need to look at the `error` property instead.

Therefore instead of:

```
reader.onerror = x => { throw x }
```

a more appropriate response is:

```
reader.onerror = () => { throw reader.error }`
```

or if you're wrapping inside a promise (as per [Javascript Promises with FileReader()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34495796)), instead of:

```
reader.onerror = reject:
```

you're better off using

```
reader.onerror = () => reject(reader.error);
```

Having said that, the error property is of type `DOMException` which does not inherit from `Error` and, in my case, contained very little useful information, but it seems to be the best there is and, as far as I could tell, throwing a `DOMException` seems to be considered acceptable practice even though it isn't an `Error`

Comment: Note that nowadays you should use the Blob's reading method instead of a FileReader. These (apart from .stream()) will return a Promise that rejects with the appropriate DOMException directly.